# latex error tikz.code.tex not found

Tags: latexmk

I have an updated latex installation using `texlive` (full), but still, on compiling, I am getting warning:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty|13 error| Could not open "tikz.code.tex"
```

where `tikx.sty` is:

```
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.


\RequirePackage{pgf,pgffor} % calc and xkeyval have been removed!

\input{tikz.code.tex}

\endinput
```

I am giving a `mwe`, with the hope that it might be of help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\synctex=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  particle2/.style={dashed,draw=PGreen, postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=at position.5 with {\arrow[PGreen]{triangle 45}}}},
  particle/.style={thick,draw=Indigo, postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=at position.5 with {\arrow[Indigo]{triangle 45}}}},
  gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,
  decoration={coil,aspect=0}}
}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=.3cm, minimum height=.1cm,text
centered, draw=dcol, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum
width=.3cm, minimum height=.1cm, text centered, draw=dcol, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=.3cm, minimum height=.1cm, text centered, text
width=6cm, draw=dcol, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=.3cm, minimum height=.1cm, text centered, text
width=3cm, draw=dcol, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, text width=5cm, text centered, draw=dcol, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth, draw=dcol]
\begin{frame}
  Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```